# Search string in ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to search for a keyword in the `ArrayList`, and If keyword is found, It prints how many "Keyword" there is in the `ArrayList`. But I get the print "No keywords found" no matter what keyword It is because the search method doesn't work for a reason.

Here's the code:

```
public ArrayList<Media> search(String keywordi)
{
    keyword = keywordi;
    System.out.println(keyword);
    return (ArrayList<Media>) storage.stream()
            .filter(m -> storage.contains(keyword))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And

```
ArrayList<Media> result = (ArrayList<Media>) katalog.search("Tasty");

    if(result.size()==0)
    {
        System.out.println("No keywords found.");

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(result.size()+" keywords found.");
    }
```

Comment: Post your relevant code here in the question.

Comment: @takendarkk there you go! :)

Comment: What is the `Media` type and how does it relate to a `String` keyword?

Comment: @zapl this is the media class. http://pastebin.com/eubUwp3y and It does not do anything special to this.

Comment: Do you want to filter by title of the media objects? `gettitel()` needs to appear in your filtering code then

Comment: I'm writing the arraylist to a txt file like this: But It's weird output in the txt file. http://pastebin.com/HRqXyHhw , why?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `filter` invocation should be

```
filter(m -> m.contains(keyword))
```

but your `Media` class does not have a `contain` method.
So maybe it should be

```
filter(m -> m.beskrivning.contains(keyword))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will helpful to your question :

```
    List<Media> list = Arrays.asList(new Media("T"), new Media("Keyword"), new Media("Keyword"),
            new Media("T"), new Media("Keyword"), new Media("Keyword"),
            new Media("F"), new Media("T"), new Media("Keyword"));
    String looking_for = "Keyword";
    long count
            = list.stream()
            .filter(i -> i.getWord().equals(looking_for)).count();
    System.out.println(count > 0 ? count + " keywords found" : "No keywords found");
```

Assuming your `Media` class like below :

```
class Media {

        private String word;

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        public Media(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you probably want is either

```
public ArrayList<Media> search(String keywordi) {
    return storage.stream()
            .filter(media -> media.gettitel() != null ? media.gettitel().contains(keywordi) : false)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

or

```
public List<Media> search(String keywordi) {
    return storage.stream() // => Stream<Media>
            .filter(media -> media.gettitel() != null ? media.gettitel().contains(keywordi) : false)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

because `ArrayList` is just a detail that doesn't matter. The generic `List` interface is usually preferable.

The `filter` is applied to every element from the `Stream<Media>` you get by calling the `stream()` method. It's a `boolean` function that decides whether the element is supposed to be present in the next step or not. If a simple expression isn't enough you can as well define a whole code block to analyze the `Media` element you get:

```
public List<Media> search(String keywordi) {
    return storage.stream()
            .filter(media -> {
                if (media.gettitel() != null && media.gettitel().contains(keywordi))
                    return true;
                if (media.getMediatyp() != null && media.getMediatyp().contains(keywordi))
                    return true;
                return false;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: @logiacer try again, I've updated the code. In case `gettitel()` can return `null`, you'll have to catch that case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I get the "No keywords found." because there is no data in the gettitel. It is stored in ArrayList<Media> storage, or correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @logiacer I have not seen `Tasty` appear anywhere in your code so I don't know where it should find that. Is it something that can be found somewhere?

Comment: I'm searching for John at the moment, tasty was only for test haha. ArrayList<Media> result = (ArrayList<Media>) katalog.search("John");

Comment: @logiacer it works for me, but I've replaced the DVD and so on classes with `Media` directly. ( see http://ideone.com/3MOyDK) Are you maybe not passing the titel in the constructors of `Bok` down to `Media`?

Comment: @logiacer yes, you don't actually extend `Media`, you ignore it :) You should set Media's titel field etc as well (call all the `set..` methods in the constructor of `Bok` or call `super(mtitel, mutgivningsår, mpris, mbeskrivning)`with proper values), otherwise that base class is useless.

Comment: Do you mean calling the bok "setförfattare" and "setantalSidor" to Media's constructor? or the opposite? I'm new at Java, sorry for being noob.

Comment: @logiacer the opposite. The `Bok` sits on top and needs to call down to the `Media`.

Comment: How do I call one constructor from another in Java?

Comment: @logiacer http://ideone.com/3MOyDK and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html